# Returning Customer

Tags: cognito-forms

I have customers re-ordering meal delivery service weekly.
I'd like for them to be able to re-order easily instead of retyping their information address etc every week. Is there any feature for returning customers, or a way to track if they are returning to avoid asking them certain questions? or not allowing them to use a specific promo code more than once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

At the moment we do not offer a graceful way of setting this up. However this will be something that can be done when the [Customer Portal](https://trello.com/c/u5WcAYkd) feature is released.